# Determine selected item from "Files" tab from within a custom Teams tab

Tags: microsoft-teams

From within a custom Teams tab, can I somehow know what items did the user select in the "Files" tab ?

I'm developing a custom Teams tab (using typescript, react, and sharepoint web parts) which can be added to any channel page (alongside Posts, Files...).
**The ideal scenario** would be that the user first selects an item in the *Files* section (eg. a folder), then opens the custom tab, and **in there** I can know what the selected item is.

Can I somehow achieve this ?

Thanks.

Comment: could this start the other way - the user begins in your custom tab, and chooses a file from a Teams Files picker of some sort?

Comment: Umm... it would have to be a folder, but yes, in case there's no other way, I could offer the user some sort of "folder-tree-browser & folder picker" tool. Is that easier to do ?

Comment: It's still only in planning, so probably won't suit your timeline, but Graph Toolkit is looking to include something like this if you can wait. See here: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-toolkit/pull/688